# Regrading decorator pattern, object instantiation

Tags: java

While studying decorator pattern I got stuck in a basic doubt as follows

Background: http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/09/decorator-design-pattern-tutorial/

- Pizza -> interface (PlainPizza & TopingDecorator(Abstract Class) implements it)
- TomatoSauce and Mozzarella extends TopingDecorator
- ToppingDecorator has an instance field Pizza

Question: How does code executer reads the following code? I tried to answer it please do confirm whether it is correct or not.

1. TomatoSauce constructor creates its object passing Mozarella object to its super
2. Its super (i.e. TopingDecorator) creates Mozzarella object (using its constructor) passing PlainPizza object as argument to its super.
3. As soon as plain pizza object is instantiated, it is stored in the instance field Pizza of Mozzarella object.
4. And then this Mozzarella object is stored in instance field of TomatoSauce. Now, the instantiation of TomatoSauce object is complete.

So, TomatoSauce Object's super contains Mozzarella object. And that Mozzarella Object's super object contain PlainPizza object.

```
   Pizza basicPizza = new TomatoSauce(new Mozzarella(new PlainPizza()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are almost there with your understanding.

```
Pizza basicPizza = new TomatoSauce(new Mozzarella(new PlainPizza()));
```

- First, `PlainPizza` object will be created
- Second, `Mozzarella` constructor will be called by passing newly created plainpizza.
- Now, the `Mozzarella` constructor will call the `super(newPizza);`, this will set the `newPizza` to `ToppingDecorator`'s instance variable.
- Now, the actual `Mozzarella` object creation is completed.

As the `Mozzerella` `is-a` `Pizza` the `TomotoSauce` constructor can take it and call the `ToppingDecorator`'s  constructor and set the `mozerella` to `ToppingDecorator`.

Now, coming to `decorator pattern`, it changes the behavior of a single instance of the `Pizza`.

When you call a method `basicPizza.getDescription();` your output will be `Thin dough, mozzarella, tomato sauce`. This means you wrapped `Thin dough` behavior with both `mozzarella` and `tomato sauce`.

If you just want to decorate your `PlainPizza` with `Mozzarella`, you do the following without changing any implementation.

```
Pizza onlyMozzarella = new Mozzarella(new PlainPizza());
```

Hope it will not make you further confused.

Comment: so it doesn't start with the constructor of TomatoSauce? It starts with the innermost argument..is that a rule in Java?